# How to use mutex in shared library that called from multy threads?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, mutex, ld-preload

I build a share library that used for `LD_PRELOAD` , that library is called by multy-threads in parallel.

I in the first time that `read` function call to call for `_init` function . I don't want to use `__attribute__(constructor)` because that library load lot of time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t lock;
static int is_init = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
static void __init()
{
    is_init = 1;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    if(is_init == 0)
        return;
    print("init.....\n");
    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

ssize_t read(int fd, void *data, size_t size) {
  if(is_init == 0)
      __init();
  strcpy(data, "I love cats");
  return 12;
}
```

But how can I init the lock with `pthread_mutex_init` that will called only 1 time ?

Comment: "*I don't want to use __attribute__(constructor) because that library load lot of time.*". That doesn't really make sense. The constructor is only called once per process. It doesn't matter how many threads you have it will only still be called once.

Comment: I believe you can use `__attribute__((constructor))`. Essentially, `__init` has it by default. And it is called once at startup (or `dlopen`) time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

or in the `__init` function

```
pthread_mutex_init(...);
```

As kaylum said earlier: "the constructor is only called once per process."

Comment: Is there static init to semaphores  too ? like `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` in mutex ?

Comment: PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER. How about a look into the man pages?